# Sharepoint 2013 Variation configuration for Translator or content author

Tags: document-library, document, variations

I‘ve set up a SharePoint 2013 publishing site with variation enabled for English and French. I have 2 sites En and FR. How should I configure the notification for translator or content author So that when there is a new document in English site library, the translator gets notified in email that there is a new document for translation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of your document library in English site library, where you set (OOTB feature) an alert which will be simply sending email as per your requirement.

**Steps to set an alert:**

1. Open the document library for which you want to receive alerts.
2. Under either the **Documents** tabs, click on **Alert Me**.
3. Choose the preferences you wish to be applied to this alert and then click on **OK**.

Read more here: [How to create an alert in a SharePoint 2013 site](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-create-an-alert-in-a-sharepoint-2013-site)

As an alternate option, you can also use

[Event Receiver to send an email](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f691db16-0a7a-43cc-b897-5517cce3b2b9/sending-emails-from-event-receiver?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) or [Send email with Workflow](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/send-email-workflow-in--sharepoint-2013-online.html).